# RegEx Substring, including string

Tags: regex

I have the following string where I would like to extract a subset of the string, up to and including a date.

Below is an example of the String:

```
This is text written on 12/19/2017 10:03:38 AM
```

I want to only return:

```
This is text written on 12/19/2017
```

I have tried the following (among many other attempt):

```
.+?(\d{1,2}/\d{2}/\d{4})
```

but this seems to return `12/19/2017 10:03:38`

Thanks for any insight!

Answer (score 2):

This should work. The problem is '/' is not escaped in your expression.

```
.+?(\d{1,2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})
```